# Is declaring [almost] everything with self. alright (Python)?

Tags: python, self

I have a habit to declare new variables with `self.` in front to make it available to all methods. This is because sometimes I thought I don't need the variable in other methods. But halfway through I realized that I need it to be accessible in other methods. Then I have to add `self.` in front of all that variable.

So my question is, besides needing to type 5 characters more each time I use a variable, are there any other disadvantages? Or, how do you overcome my problem?

Comment: These variables are either part of the object's state or they aren't. If they part of the object's state, then prefix them with `self.`, otherwise don't. If you don't know if they are part of the object's state or not, then you should stop coding for a few minutes and actually think about what the heck you are doing.

Comment: You know, sometimes halfway through coding, Hey! I think I should functionize this code; it's getting too long!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set a property on `self` only when the value is part of the overall object state.  If it's only part of the method state, then it should be method-local, and should not be a property of `self`.

Comment: Right. Making everything part of `self` is almost as bad as making everything a global variable. Think about what you're doing!

Comment: As well as the potential confusion of the "class global"-ness of your variables, you're adding additional overhead on every reference to a value, as you're going from quick local scope references to attribute look-ups every single time. This is why you'll sometimes see code like `foo = self.foo[;] for x in xrange(HUGE_VALUE): foo()`.  It saves doing a more expensive attribute look-up on each iteration of the long-running loop.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really allright. `self` makes your variable available to global object-scope. That way you need to make sure that names of your variables are unique throughout complete object, rather than in localized scopes, amongst other side-effects that might or might not be unwanted.

In your particular case it might be not an issue, but it's a very bad practice in general.

Know your scoping and use it wisely. :)